# Local User Stuck on "Current Password"

Tags: windows

In our EC2 instance, we have created multiple users in a Remote Desktop group. We set a default password and want to allow users to be able to change their password when they remote desktop into the instance. They're able to use the default password to log in.

We are trying to take the following steps to change password: `Start > Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > Change password`

When the user enters the default password (used to log in into the instance) into the  "Current Password" textbox, they receive the error "Password is incorrect. Try again."

I have a feeling it's maybe a group policy setting or a local security policy of some type. When I am logged in as "Administrator" and type in the password in "Current Password" box, it takes me to the next screen to change my password without any error.

We have tried modifying the "Minimum password age" to 0 day in the security policy, but this did not fix the issue.

I'm using "CIS Benchmark Windows Server 2019 - Level 1". We do not encounter this issue in a "non CIS Benchmark" server.